# How to exclude content with the same taxonomy term as the page containing the view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

slightly odd one here but I have to create an archive page but want to ensure I don't display the content of the 'live' issue.

So, I have a taxonomy of Issue Number - every page in the site has to have this to ensure they show up in the correct archive in the future but on the Archive page I only want to display content from previous Issues so want to exclude any content with the same Issue number as the Archive page the user is viewing.

I know how to exclude the current page from a view (ie: when created a view for related articles) and I've been able to exclude certain other taxonomy terms but how do I exclude the current?

Thanks

Stew

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out what to do! So just in case you have the same problem:

Use Pager | Display All items | Offset 1

and then the most recent item will not be displayed.

Perfect